# Different number of divs based on how large is the screen best practices?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I am having a problem regarding elements inside a flex box. I am using `flex: 1 1 auto` with `flex-flow: column wrap`. I want to show a number of divs whose size increases along with that of the screen.

Using media queries would be so confusing and the code would be so large. I am searching for a way to achieve it without using media queries because the size of each div in the flex is about 200px each, I would need to make a lot of media queries incrementing from low to high resolutions.

Comment: show your code or what you have done so far here so we can visualize the problem and help you.

Answer (score 0):

The min-width property is rather useful here. I put fifteen divs to show the effect on multiple screen sizes.

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* this makes the divs wrap */
}
.flex-child {
  margin: 3px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-width: 200px; /*prevents the flex-child from shrinking more than 200px */
  height: 50px;
  flex: auto; /* this auto-adjusts the width */
  
  /* Everything after this is just to align everything to the center */
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-parent'>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
  <div class='flex-child'>CHILD</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use `flex-flow: row wrap`.**

If you want to show more `div` elements as the screen gets *wider*, you’ll want to use `row` for `flex-direction`, not `column`. With `flex-direction: row`, the flex items will be put into each line from left to right, like a line of text. And the bigger the screen, the more items will fit.

If you want your flex items to grow and fill all the available space, use `flex: auto`. This might mean the items end up with different sizes, because you can have a different number of items in each flex line. If you want all of them to be the same size, you could set something like `flex: 200px`.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 8px;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: auto;
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: bisque;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">One</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Two</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Three</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Four</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Five</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Six</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Seven</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Eight</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Nine</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Ten</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Eleven</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Twelve</div>
</div>
```

If you want to arrange the `div` elements as *columns* (top to bottom), then your flex container needs to have a `height` set on it, for example `height: 500px`. This is so that the flex container can calculate how many flex items can fit into each column.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  gap: 8px;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: auto;
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: bisque;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">One</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Two</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Three</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Four</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Five</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Six</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Seven</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Eight</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Nine</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Ten</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Eleven</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Twelve</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used your suggestion, I have hidden the overflow and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help.